# Python3 write gzip file - memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, gzip, typeerror, python-3.5

I want to write a file. Based on the name of the file this may or may not be compressed with the `gzip` module. Here is my code:

```
import gzip
filename = 'output.gz'
opener = gzip.open if filename.endswith('.gz') else open
with opener(filename, 'wb') as fd:
    print('blah blah blah'.encode(), file=fd)
```

I'm opening the writable file in binary mode and encoding my string to be written. However I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/gzip.py", line 258, in write
  data = memoryview(data)
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Why is my object not a bytes? I get the same error if I open the file with `'w'` and skip the encoding step. I also get the same error if I remove the `'.gz'` from the filename.

I'm using Python3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Its the same as `print(str('blah blah blah'.encode()), file=fd)`. python is trying to write the string representation of the bytes object.

Comment: @nic you can use the 'wt' flag and write strings directly - see my answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`print` is a relatively complex function. It writes `str` to a file but not the `str` that you pass, it writes the `str` that is the result of rendering the parameters.

If you have bytes already, you can use `fd.write(bytes)` directly and take care of adding a newline if you need it.

If you don't have bytes, make sure `fd` is opened to receive text.

Comment: use 'fd.write(b"blah blah blah")'

Comment: @citizenSNIPS, I don't understand you comment.

Comment: add a 'b' infront of the str to signify it is a byte. I believe you want to pass a bytes-literal. [](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3112/)

Comment: I do not. I only mention types, no sample data.

Comment: I see. my point was if the file was opened using `wb`, then the `str` would need to be a `byte`, and adding `b` infront would do that.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that feature. Thanks.

Comment: @Javier, thanks for your answer. Looks like I'll be converting to write from now on.

Answer (score 26):

For me, changing the gzip flag to **'wt'** did the job. I could write the original string, without "byting" it.
(tested on python 3.5, 3.7 on ubuntu 16).

From [python 3 gzip doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) - quoting: "... The mode argument can be any of 'r', 'rb', 'a', 'ab', 'w', 'wb', 'x' or 'xb' for binary mode, **or 'rt', 'at', 'wt', or 'xt' for text mode**..."

```
import gzip

filename = 'output.gz'
opener = gzip.open if filename.endswith('.gz') else open
with opener(filename, 'wt') as fd:
    print('blah blah blah', file=fd)

!zcat output.gz
> blah blah blah
```

Comment: I think this answer is already a better one (even looking at votes). Shall we change this response to the "accepted" answer?

Answer (score 14):

you can convert it to bytes like this.

```
import gzip 
with gzip.open(filename, 'wb') as fd:
   fd.write('blah blah blah'.encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`io.TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) as intermediate buffer:

```
import gzip
import io

filename = 'output.gz'
opener = gzip.open if filename.endswith('.gz') else open
with opener(filename, 'wb') as fd:
    print('blah blah blah', file=io.TextIOWrapper(fd, write_through=True))
```

Output:

```
# For a gzip file
>>> !zcat output.gz
blah blah blah

# For a text file
>>> !cat output.txt
blah blah blah
```

Answer (score -2):

You can serialize it using `pickle`.

First serializing the `object` to be written using `pickle`, then using `gzip`.

To **save** the `object`:

```
import gzip, pickle
filename = 'non-serialize_object.zip'
# serialize the object    
serialized_obj = pickle.dumps(object)
# writing zip file
with gzip.open(filename, 'wb') as f:
   f.write(serialized_obj)
```

To **load** the `object`:

```
import gzip, pickle
filename = 'non-serialize_object.zip'

with gzip.open(filename, 'rb') as f:    
   serialized_obj = f.read()
# de-serialize the object
object = pickle.loads(serialized_obj)
```