# Python gzip gives error and asks for bytes like input

Tags: python, file-io, gzip

I'm unable to get this to work

```
import gzip
content = "Lots of content here"
f = gzip.open('file.txt.gz', 'a', 9)
f.write(content)
f.close()
```

I get output:

```
============== RESTART: C:/Users/Public/Documents/Trial_vr06.py ==============
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Public/Documents/Trial_vr06.py", line 4, in <module>
    f.write(content)
  File "C:\Users\SONID\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\gzip.py", line 260, in write
    data = memoryview(data)
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

This was linked in an answer [Python Gzip - Appending to file on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097107/python-gzip-appending-to-file-on-the-fly) to [Is it possible to compress program output within python to reduce output file's size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46707020/is-it-possible-to-compress-program-output-within-python-to-reduce-output-files?noredirect=1#comment80361232_46707020)

I've tried integer data but no effect. What is the issue here

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56282647/1361125) has the same question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by default `gzip` streams are *binary* ([Python 3: gzip.open() and modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013083/python-3-gzip-open-and-modes)).

No problem in Python 2, but Python 3 makes a difference between binary & text streams.

So either encode your string (or use `b` prefix if it's a literal like in your example, not always possible)

```
f.write(content.encode("ascii"))
```

or maybe better for text only: open the `gzip` stream as *text*:

```
f = gzip.open('file.txt.gz', 'at', 9)
```

note that append mode on a `gzip` file works is not that efficient ([Python Gzip - Appending to file on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097107/python-gzip-appending-to-file-on-the-fly))

Comment: Thanks. Is this a change only for Py3.x?

Answer (score 0):

In order to compress your string, it must be a binary value. In order to do that simply put a "b" in front of your string. This will tell the interpreter to read this as the binary value and not the string value.

`content = b"Lots of content here"`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could it cause some changes when I later read this data from the output file a program?

Comment: All you'll need to do is set the flag as "rb" or some other form denoting binary and you'll be set without any issues.